# how to create hive table with '@' in struct type column?

Tags: hadoop, hive

hive creata sql:
`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`warehouse`.`aaa`(`
properties`struct<`
sk@aaa`:string
>
)
PARTITIONED BY (`dt`string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
)
STORED AS
  INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs://.....';`

error message:

`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: : expected at the position 9 of 'struct<sk@aaa:string>' but '@' is found`

how to create hive table with @ in struct column?

Comment: Try backticks around the filed name: ``struct<`sk@aaa`:string>``.

Answer (score 1):

You can use backticks in case of special characters for HBase 0.13 and later version.

```
struct<`sk@aaa`:string>
```

Please refer documentation for more details : 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select

```
In Hive 0.12 and earlier, only alphanumeric and underscore characters are allowed in table and column names.
In Hive 0.13 and later, column names can contain any Unicode character (see HIVE-6013). Any column name that is specified within backticks (`) is treated literally. Within a backtick string, use double backticks (``) to represent a backtick character.
To revert to pre-0.13.0 behavior and restrict column names to alphanumeric and underscore characters, set the configuration property hive.support.quoted.identifiers to none. In this configuration, backticked names are interpreted as regular expressions. For details, see Supporting Quoted Identifiers in Column Names (attached to HIVE-6013). Also see REGEX Column Specification below.
```